# Почему таблица при success'е появляется на мгновение и исчезает, как сделать чтобы она отобразилась и осталась на месте?

Tags: php, jquery

После ввода информации форма отправляется на сервер там добавляется в текстовый файл, из этого файла полностью собирается таблица как вернуть эту таблицу на клиент и отобразить ее при помощи jQuery?

Клиент:
index.html

```
<form method="POST" id="addproduct" onsubmit="call()">
Производитель: <input type="text" name="inp1"><br />
Наименование: <input type="text" name="inp2"><br />
Цена: <input type="text" name="inp3"><br />
Количество: <input type="text" name="inp4"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call() {
        var msg   = $('#addproduct').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file_w_r.php',
            data: msg,
            success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
            },
            error:  function(xhr, str){
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Сервер:
file_w_r.php

```
<?php
    $array = file('testfile.txt');
    $last_str = count($array) + 1;
    $rowsall = $last_str + 1;
    $br = ' :: ';
    $proi = $_POST['inp1'];
    $naim = $_POST['inp2'];
    $cena = $_POST['inp3'];
    $kolvo = $_POST['inp4'];
    $text .= $last_str . $br . $proi . $br . $naim . $br . $cena . $br . $kolvo . "\r\n";
    $filename = 'testfile.txt';
    $handler = fopen($filename, "a+");
    fwrite($handler, $text);

    $data = file($filename);

    $total_price = 0;
    $total_count = 0;
?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="<?=$rowsall?>"></th>
    <th>Производитель</th>
    <th>Наименование</td>
    <th>Цена</th>
    <th>Кол-во</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($data as $value):
        $value = explode(" :: ", $value);

        $total_price += $value[3];
        $total_count += $value[4];      
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?=$value[1]?></td>
    <td><?=$value[2]?></td>
    <td><?=$value[3]?></td>
    <td><?=$value[4]?></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
<tr><th>Итого:</th><td colspan="2"></td><td><?=$total_price?></td><td><?=$total_count?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Вопрос то в чём? У вас же весь код есть

Comment: Таблица на клиенте не отображаеться

Comment: Ну так ищите проблему. За вас никто этого сделать не сможет. Смотрите что ajax возвращает (если возвращает). Смотрите что на сервер приходит.

Comment: Как посмотреть что возвращает?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас перезагружается страница, после события `onsubmit`, нужно отменить стандартное поведение формы. Удалите с формы `onsubmit="call()"` и `method="POST"` оставте только `id`

```
<form <!-- удалите это: method="POST" --> id="addproduct" <!-- и это: onsubmit="call()" -->>
```

Теперь будем вызывать `AJAX` из `js`

> Поменяйте местами чтобы jQuery подключался выше, и только после него шел ваш
>   скрипт

```
<form id="addproduct">
    Производитель:
    <input type="text" name="inp1">
    <br> Наименование:
    <input type="text" name="inp2">
    <br> Цена:
    <input type="text" name="inp3">
    <br> Количество:
    <input type="text" name="inp4">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>

<div id="results"></div>

<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Вешаем обработчик на событие формы
    $('#addproduct').on('submit', function(event) {
        // отменяем стандартное поведение формы
        event.preventDefault();
       // делаем запрос
       call();
    });

    function call() {
      var msg = $('#addproduct').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file_w_r.php',
        data: msg,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#results').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, str) {
          alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```